Bad-Elf With an iPhone: cannot be paired
I am new with using Qfield on my iPhone XR (formerly with Cartomobile). I do try to link the external Bad-Elf GNSS Surveyor in QField using Parameter-Positionning-Add but the Bad-Elf GPS is not showing, only a suggested IP address. When I click on the proposed link, an error window appear at the bottom:

Connection refused by distant host.

Any suggestions?

Looks like you can’t couple QField directly to an iPhone via Bluetooth. So I used an other app (NMEA GPS) to link the 2 together. There maybe other solutions but that one worked for me.
